# Django - Get Foreign key objects in single query?

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I'm finding django foreign keys a bit confusing, is there any way to do the view below, using a single query?

```
# Model
class Programme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

class Actor(models.Model):
    programme = models.ForeignKey(Programme)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)


# View
def list_actors( request, programme_id):
    programme = Programme.objects.filter(id = programme_id)[0]
    actors = Actor.objects.filter(programme = programme_id)
    json = simplejson.dumps( [{
        'name': str(actor.name),
        'rating': str(actor.rating),} for actor in actors] )
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You query `Programme` and assign to `programme`, but you never use the result anywhere. Just remove that line.

Answer (score 32):

I think you are looking for [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

This line:

```
actors = Actor.objects.filter(programme = programme_id)
```

should look like this:

```
actors = Actor.objects.select_related().filter(programme = programme_id)
```

Unfortunately as emphasized here: [Get foreign key objects in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832997/get-foreign-key-objects-in-a-single-query-django) you will only be able to retrieve actors that way as `select_related` only works on objects having ForeignKeys and not vice versa.

Comment: `select_related` would only be needed if you wanted to access `actor.programme.name` without an extra DB hit per actor. Otherwise it's superfluous.