# Get foreign key objects in a single query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 2 models in my Django code:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    modela_link = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, 'modelb_link')
    functions = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Say ModelA has 100 records, all of which may or may not have links to ModelB

Now say I want to get a list of every ModelA record along with the data from ModelB

I would do:

```
list_a = ModelA.objects.all()
```

Then to get the data for ModelB I would have to do

```
for i in list_a:
    i.additional_data = i.modelb_link.all()
```

However, this runs a query on every instance of i.  Thus making 101 queries to run.

Is there any way of running this all in just 1 query? Or at least less than the 101 queries.

I've tried putting in `ModelA.objects.select_related().all()` but this didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Ofri says, `select_related` only works on forwards relations, not reverse ones.

There's no built-in way to automatically follow reverse relations in Django, but see [my blog post](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/) for a technique to do it reasonably efficiently. The basic idea is to get all the related objects for every item at once, then associate them manually with their related item - so you can do it in 2 queries rather than n+1.

Answer (score 1):

Django ORM is a good thing but some some things is better to do manually.
You may import connection cursor and execute raw sql in single query.

```
from django.db import connection
cur=connection.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

your query should look like (*for MySQL*)

```
SELECT * FROM appname_modela INNER JOIN appname_modelb ON appname_modela.id=appname_modelb.modela_link_id
```

Comment: I know that when using raw sql you don't get an object returned so do you know of any way to convert the results into a Django object

Comment: currently you cant create raw sql results into django queryset

Answer (score 1):

The reason .select_related() didn't work, is that .select_related() is used to follow foreign keys. Your ModelA doesn't have a foreign key to ModelB. Its ModelB that has a foreign key to ModelA. (so a ModelA instance can have multiple ModelB instances related to it).

You could use this to do it in 2 queries, and a bit of python code:

```
list_b = ModelB.objects.all()
list_a = ModelA.objects.all()
for a in list_a:
    a.additional_data = [b for b in list_b if b.modela_link_id==a.id]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

newest = ModelB.objects.filter(modela_link=OuterRef('pk'))
ModelA.objects.annotate(newest=Subquery(newest))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30204729)